# Read columns from csv in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, io, file-handling

I have a csv file with columns id, name, address, phone. I want to read each row such that I store the data in two variables, `key` and `data`, where data contains name, address and phone. I want to do this because I want to append another column country in each row in a new csv. Can anyone help me with the code in python. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
dict = {}
reader = csv.reader(open('info.csv', 'r'))
for row in reader:
    key, *data = row
    dict[key] = ','.join(data)
```

Comment: `key, *data = row` only works in Python 3...

Comment: Can you provide some example input and output?

Answer (score 3):

`key, *data = row` is Python 3 syntax. For Python 2 you can do this:

```
key, data = row[0], row[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below. I have put two option one is to make a list for each row, and other is comma separated. Based on the usage you can use either one.

```
import csv
dict = {}
reader = csv.reader(open('info.csv', 'r'))
for row in reader:
    data = []
    print row
    key,data = row[0],row[1:]
    dict[key] = data
    # dict[key] = ','.join(data)
print dict
```